# Best approach to display empty rows for ASP.MVC 3 with EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, scheduling

I have problem with displaying table with hours and attendance for some all day event. This event allows to signing up attendees for each hour of day. I wonder what is the best approach to display count of attendees for each hour of that day? Problem is with hours which has no attendees signed on. What is the best approach to display this "empty" rows (hours with zero value)? I came to solution, that I can handle this in some stored procedure which will be mapped to some entities used for display only, but I don't like this way very much. What is the best approach for this problem? I am using ASP.MVC 3 with Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that you treat your database schema as view model.

You should introduce model classes that will correspond to what the view is displaying. You will be than able to create in controller 'empty' instances of those models, with hours set to 0. Those model will be than translated to EF entities in your controller and persisted.

By effectively binding your database schema to views you've limited your options. MVC is all about decoupling of views and data persistence.

Yes, in simple scenarios you can get away with passing your EF entities to views, but in more complex ones (like the one you've encountered) decoupling is necessary.

Comment: Yes, I know, that binding db directly to view is not best idea. My idea was to create procedure which output would be binded to some EF entinty, which would be bounded to view by some controller. Hovewer I don't like this idea very much (having entity in EF used only for displaying data) so I'm asking, if is there some other and better solution.

Comment: The answer is to create a new model class, which is *not* an EF entity.

Comment: You mean have collection of X objects (number depends of opened hours of event) of some viewmodel class? Sorry but I'm still having quite a hard time to get used to MVC :)

Comment: More or less, you know your domain best. The idea is to create brand new classes that the view will use, and not to pass EF entities to the view.